# How to loop through JSON Nested array values in PHP? Datatable

Tags: php, mysql, json, datatable

My database in mysql has a table called "sales" where there is a field "products" where several products are "sold" in json and within this json I just need to get the information "brand" and "model" to show it in a datatable, Thanks.

Here is the image of my table.

[image]

```
Here is the json [{"id":"312","marca":"NIKON","modelo":"D3400","serie":"8857882","cantidad":"1","stock":"0","precio":"1669","total":"1669"},{"id":"161","marca":"NIKON","modelo":"AF-P NIKKOR 18-55MM 1:3.5-5.6G","serie":"21963658","cantidad":"1","stock":"0","precio":"0","total":"0"}]

public function mostrarTablaSell(){
    $item = null;
    $valor = null;
    $orden = "id";

    $ventas = ControladorVentas::ctrMostrarVentas($item, $valor, $orden);   

    if(count($ventas) == 0){
        echo '{"data": []}';
        return;
    }

    $datosJson = '{
                  "data": [';
    for($i = 0; $i < count($ventas); $i++){
        /*=============================================
          PRODUCTOS
          =============================================*/ 
        $here = json_decode($ventas[$i]["productos"], true);

        foreach ($here as $key => $value) {
            $productos1 = $value['marca'];
            $productos2 = $value['modelo'];
        }

        //$productos0 = $here[0]['categoria'];
        //$productos1 = $here[0]['marca'];
        //$productos2 = $here[0]['modelo'];
        $productos = $productos1 .' '. $productos2;

        /*=============================================
          TRAEMOS LAS ACCIONES
          =============================================*/ 
        if(isset($_GET["perfilOculto"]) && $_GET["perfilOculto"] == "Especial"){
            $botones =  "<div class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-warning btnEditarVenta' idVenta='".$ventas[$i]["id"]."'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></button><button class='btn btn-danger btnEliminarVenta' idVenta='".$ventas[$i]["id"]." '><i class='fa fa-times'></i></button><button class='btn btn-info btnImprimirFactura' codigoVenta='".$ventas[$i]["codigo"]."'><i class='fa fa-print'></i></button></div>"; 
        }else{
            $botones =  "<div class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-warning btnEditarVenta' idVenta='".$ventas[$i]["id"]."'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></button><button class='btn btn-danger btnEliminarVenta' idVenta='".$ventas[$i]["id"]." '><i class='fa fa-times'></i></button><button class='btn btn-info btnImprimirFactura' codigoVenta='".$ventas[$i]["codigo"]."'><i class='fa fa-print'></i></button></div>"; 
        }

        $datosJson .='[
                              "'.($i+1).'",
                              "'.$ventas[$i]["id"].'",
                              "'.$ventas[$i]["codigo"].'",
                              "'.$vendedor.'",
                              "'.$cliente.'",
                              "'.$ventas[$i]["proviene"].'",
                              "'.$productos.'",
                              "'.$ventas[$i]["desp"].'",
                               "'.$ventas[$i]["adelanto"].'",
                              "'.$ventas[$i]["total"].'",
                              "'.$ventas[$i]["estado"].'",
                              "'.$ventas[$i]["obs"].'",
                              "'.$ventas[$i]["fecha"].'",
                              "'.$botones.'"
                            ],';
    }
    $datosJson = substr($datosJson, 0, -1);
    $datosJson .=   '] 
                 }';
    echo $datosJson;
}
}
```

Comment: Please avoid manually constructing a json output string.  `json_encode()` exists for a reason.  Aren't both `$botones` declarations the same? Why the condition block?

Comment: and to add to @mickmackusa 's comment why do you store products in JSON formats in a database?  You can never easy search those and use indexing on JSON... Ideally you should normalise that data or use a NoSQL database.. Time for MySQL to support JSONB (Binary JSON) format and native index support like PostgreSQL has.

Comment: @mickmackusa I don't know an easy way to convert the image to text.

Comment: I've been busy fixing the code indentation, instead of actually working on an answer, go for it!

Comment: [{"id":"312","marca":"NIKON","modelo":"D3400","serie":"8857882","cantidad":"1","stock":"0","precio":"1669","total":"1669"},{"id":"161","marca":"NIKON","modelo":"AF-P NIKKOR 18-55MM 1:3.5-5.6G","serie":"21963658","cantidad":"1","stock":"0","precio":"0","total":"0"}]

Comment: only marca and modelo pls =D

Comment: all my system is in javascript

Comment: @RaymondNijland - `19 April 2018 — MySQL adds NoSQL and many new enhancements to the world’s most popular`  MySql 8  And `JSON - Extended syntax, new functions, improved sorting, and partial updates. With JSON table functions you can use the SQL machinery for JSON data`  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html

Comment: "19 April 2018 — MySQL adds NoSQL" i know @ArtisticPhoenix but MySQL's "NoSQL" interface is just a layer on top of SQL.. The MySQL "NoSQL" interface is just a InnoDB table and a JSON column under the hood and indexable with a generated column.  Which converts NoSQL API into plain SQL queries.. The document store already existed in [MySQL 5.7](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/05/24/looking-inside-the-mysql-5-7-document-store/) here you can see the layer on top of SQL by the way.. And yes MySQL 8 improved alot with JSON functions i agree with you on that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand your goal.  Here's a snippet...

Code : ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ViIFd))

```
$ventas[0]["productos"] = '[{"id":"312","marca":"NIKON","modelo":"D3400","serie":"8857882","cantidad":"1","stock":"0","precio":"1669","total":"1669"},{"id":"161","marca":"NIKON","modelo":"AF-P NIKKOR 18-55MM 1:3.5-5.6G","serie":"21963658","cantidad":"1","stock":"0","precio":"0","total":"0"}]';
// do not write the above sample data in your code.

$data = [];

foreach ($ventas as $row) {
    foreach (json_decode($row["productos"], true) as $details) {
        $data[] = [$details['marca'], $details['modelo']];
    }
}

echo json_encode(['data' => $data]);
```

Output:

```
{"data":[["NIKON","D3400"],["NIKON","AF-P NIKKOR 18-55MM 1:3.5-5.6G"]]}
```

Using `foreach` instead of `for` spares the need to `count` and provides simpler syntax.

Using `json_encode()` as the final step makes the code much more stable and easy to read.

You really, REALLY should normalize your table structure to permit easier/better querying.  Storing as json requires more handling and ruins opportunities to craft clever/direct queries.